# How to catch the error in loop of geocode and continue the loop

Tags: python

I am new to python, and as usual, I am running to some trouble. I am trying to store the result of `api.geocode(place)` to the list `location` using a loop, but the loop stops when no match for the place is found. Here is a minimal example.

```
from gmaps import Geocoding
api = Geocoding(api_key = 'API Key')
address = ["Philippines", "Canada", "No place like this, Australia", "Malaysia"]
location = []
for place in address:
    location.append(api.geocode(place))
```

This throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-54-8a375b31e18c>", line 2, in <module>
    location.append(api.geocode(place))

  File "/home/quack/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gmaps/geocoding.py", line 37, in geocode
    return self._make_request(self.GEOCODE_URL, parameters, "results")

  File "/home/quack/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gmaps/client.py", line 89, in _make_request
    )(response)

NoResults: {'results': [], 'status': 'ZERO_RESULTS', 'url': 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=No+place+like+this%2C+Australia&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyA-lk2z3VIZuKAq27ooswFPqjIKUDlMC2M'}
```

I tried to use a `try` and `except` solution like the following:

```
for place in address:
    try:
        location.append(api.geocode(place))
    except:
        pass
```

This results to a list `location` of length 3. How would I indicate `NoResult` in place of the result for `No place like this, Australia` and continue with the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I understand your question correctly:

```
from gmaps import Geocoding
api = Geocoding(api_key = 'API Key')
address = ["Philippines", "Canada", "No place like this, Australia", "Malaysia"]
location = []
for place in address:
    try:
        location.append(api.geocode(place))
    except Exception as e:
        location.append("No Result")
```

but a better approach would be :

```
from gmaps import Geocoding
api = Geocoding(api_key = 'API Key')
address = ["Philippines", "Canada", "No place like this, Australia", "Malaysia"]
location = {}
for place in address:
    try:
        location[place] = api.geocode(place)
    except Exception as e:
        location[place] = "No Result"
```

build a dictionary where u can see which places do not exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the raised `NoResults` exception to your `location` list.

```
for place in address:
    try:
        location.append(api.geocode(place))
    except Exception as exc:
        location.append(exc)
```